# How can I send an email from a JSP? I have an error

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to send an email from a JSP using gmail, I tested my code in a normal Java Application (not web) and it works well, but I have this problem
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.setApplicationProtocols([Ljava/lang/String;)V`
when I run the JSP, here is my code

```
<%
    String result = "failed";
    
    Properties props = new Properties();
    
    String gmailAccount = "mymail@gmail.com";
    String gmailPassword = "mypass";
    String body = "<h1>Hello!</h1>";
    String subject = "Test";
    String to = "destinationmail@gmail.com";
    Session sessionmail;
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    sessionmail = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(gmailAccount, gmailPassword);
        }
    });
    
    try {
        MimeBodyPart a = new MimeBodyPart();
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        mimeBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
        Message message = new MimeMessage(sessionmail);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(gmailAccount));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport transport = sessionmail.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", gmailAccount, gmailPassword);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        result = "Ok";
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        result = "failed";
    }
%>
```

By the way, I am using `jdk 1.8.0_251` and Payara server 5.194 (I tried by using glassfish but I got the same error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code works in a console app, but throws that exception in Payara and Glassfish, then it most likely is an issue caused by the server loading a JAR file that contains a different version of that class.

[This list of errors for Glassfish](https://aripd.com/posts/glassfish/#errors) mentions `grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar`. See the third error. Looking for [the file in combination with your error](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar%22%20and%20%22java.lang.NoSuchMethodError%3A%20sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.setApplicationProtocols%22) shows other results that mention the same cause for the problem.

Look for that file in your server installation and rename it to `grizzly-npn-bootstrap.old` (or try newer versions of the server), then try again.